# Get the SIFT descriptor for specified point using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift, keypoint

I want get the SIFT feature for specified points. These points is gotten by hand not by KeyPoint Detector. My question is: I only know the **position** of the points but have no idea about the **size** and **angle** value. How should I set this value?

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    Mat img_object = imread("img/test.jpg", 0);

    SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat descriptors;
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

    // set keypoint position and size: should I set 
    // size parameter to 32 for 32x32 patch?
    KeyPoint kp(50, 60, 32);
    keypoints.push_back(kp);

    extractor.compute( img_object, keypoints, descriptors );

    return 0;
}
```

Should I set the size param of KeyPoint to 32 for 32x32 patch. Is this implementation reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, keypoint detectors work on a local neighbourhood around a point. This is the `size` field of OpenCV's `KeyPoint` class. The `angle` field is the dominant orientation of the keypoint (this could be set to -1, note).

[OpenCV KeyPoint class](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=featuredetector#FeatureDetector)

[Another reference here.](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html)

Comment: And setting size to 32 means: a 32x32 local neighbourhood patch around a point, right?

Comment: I'd say so, yes. But it is quite meaningless since what you are marking are just points and not keypoints. It'll be a question of what these points are used for in the next stage of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! In face these points are landmark points of face and will be used for face alignment.

Comment: Yes, right. I'm familiar with such a technique. Consider marking an answer correct if it does solve your problem.