# Python 2.7 OpenCV: Extracting features/descriptors from image coordinates

Tags: python, opencv

I extracted several points (x,y-coordinates) of interest from my image using OpenCV in Python (i.e. Thresholding, contourfinding, moments). Now, I want to match those points with a reference pattern to exclude falsy detected points. My approach is to match the features/descriptors from the image points with the features/descriptors of the reference pattern, but I don't know how to extract features/descriptors from the image points.

How do I extract features/descriptors from the given coordinates using OpenCV in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use [KeyPoint](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=featuredetector#FeatureDetector)

```
import cv2
surf = cv2.SURF() #Should works with another descriptors
customKeyPoints = [cv2.KeyPoint(<your coords, size, angle, etc>), 
                   cv2.KeyPoint(<your coords, size, angle, etc>), ...]
surf.compute(img, customKeyPoints)
#Should return you descriptors from specified points
```

[Similiar question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285210/get-the-sift-descriptor-for-specified-point-using-opencv)

PS Sorry for my English